# monodevelop lost subversion support after upgrading from snow leopard to snow lion

Tags: svn, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I had monodevelop (3.0.4) running fine in Snow leopard. I upgraded to snow lion following this procedude:
1- upgrade to snow lion
2- install monotouch
3- install xcode

I had no need to install monodevelop as it was already installed.

After this my MD environment does not have a subversion option in the publish menu.

What to do?

Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

launch xCode
 Preferences / Download tab / install command line tools